# Prove minimum of piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$F(x)= 
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{\tan x}{x}, x \neq 0\\
1, x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Prove that there is a minimum at $x=0$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** show that $\tan(x) \geq 0$ iff $x \geq 0$. From here, you need to conclude that $F$ is bounded below by $0$. Then you need to show that $F$ actually takes the value of $0$ for some $x$.

**hint 2:** $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$. Note that $\cos$ is even, and $\sin$ is odd!

Comment: Thanks! How do I prove that? That was my question this one is very challenging for me

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that was your question, you should include exactly what part is challenging in the question box, so that SE users can be more useful!

Comment: How to prove that there is a minimum at x=0? I do have knowledge of trigonometric derivatives but not if any theorems involving calculus

Comment: @Natalya As written in the answer (which you must understand), $\;\frac{\tan x}x>0\;$ for all $\;x\neq 0\;$ for which $\;\tan x\;$ is defined (perhaps you should restrict the domain of definition to $\;(-\pi/2,\,\pi/2)\;$ , and that gives you at once the minimal point $\;(0,0)\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo makes sense! but my question is how to prove it fully? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @Natalya By the very definition of $\;\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\;$ , for example... Basic trigonometry must be old, well known stuff for anyone attempting to solve this question, in my opinion.

Comment: @Natalya I think it would be a mistake to give a full solution, that's not really in the spirit of the website. When you ask for a "proof," everyone needs to logically begin **somewhere**, and usually that's clear from what is typically assumed in, say, a trigonometry class. However, in this case, there's no way to gauge what you know and what can be assumed. It would help if you showed an effort or attempt at a solution, so that we can help better.

Comment: more directly, however: there are a lot of ways to prove that something is a "minimum." In this case, we show that $F \geq 0$ (it is bounded below by $0$) and then use the fact that $F(x)=0$ for some $x$, and so $0$ must be a minimum.

Comment: @Andres I did try it but for my level i found it very challenging and was not able to solve this problem. Sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: of course it's challenging! But I can't tell *why*. What about it in particular is difficult for you? Is there something I've written that you can't understand?

Comment: Well yes, but my trouble is the proof part since I did visualize the graph already, however I need to prove it without the graph that's my problem how to actually prove it

Answer (score 1):

For $0<x<\frac\pi2$ we $\tan x>x$. For $x<0$ use that $F$ is even.